# Empty string in an ambiguous grammar?

Tags: regular-languages, context-free, regular-expressions, strings

I'm a bit confused by the role of the empty string in this ambiguous grammar:

```
A' -> A
A -> if A B
A -> null
B -> [empty string]
B -> else S
```

So what does B -> empty string mean/do? Does that mean B could transition to A? And "if", "else", and "null are terminals, then what is the empty string?

Comment: It appears that "empty string" is also a terminal. Also, your first production should be $S\rightarrow A$.

Answer (score 1):

In a grammar when a rule transitions to the empty string, that means that the symbol just disappears. For example, here is a possible derivation:

```
A'
A
if A B
if null B
if null
```

Notice that on the last line, `B` is replaced by the empty string -- nothing. It goes away. (We could have instead decided to replace B by `else S`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate `B` by substituting all its expansions wherever it appears, giving the equivalent grammar

```
A' -> A
A -> if A
A -> if A else S
A -> null
```